# Check whether a character is ( { [ using regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check whether a character is one of `(`,`[`,`{`
I can do it like this

```
if char == "{" ||  char == "(" || char == "["
```

But I want to use regular expressions to achieve this.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight-forward, you just add them to a set:

```
BRACKETS = /[\{\(\[]/

if (char.match(BRACKETS))
  # ...
end
```

Where in a regular expression `[...]` represents a set of matching single characters.

To test that it's *only* that type of character:

```
BRACKETS = /\A[\{\(\[]\z/
```

Now the simplest refactoring of your code without using a regular expression is this:

```
case (char)
when '{', '(', '['
  # ...
end
```

That may or may not be faster than a regular expression, so if performance is key, you might want to test that approach as well.

Comment: Could you use `Regexp::quote` to help with the backslashes?

Comment: You could, but it's not a huge deal to do manually. That function is useful when you're dealing with arbitrary user data and you don't know what you'll have to escape.

Comment: @squiguy The better function in this case would be [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union), as in `Regexp.union('{', '[', '(')`.

Comment: why you escape all brackets? I think that you should do it only with `[`

Comment: Technically you can get away with that, but force-escaping them makes it clear they're special. Personal preference. An unescaped `(` reads as a grouping operator to me.

Answer (score 2):

Since `[` is a special character you have to escape it in a regex grouping `[]`.

```
if char.match /[({\[]/
  # Your code here
end
```

If the character is found [`#match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match) will return a [`MatchData`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/MatchData.html) object. Else `#match` will return `nil` if the matching character is not found.

Comment: this example doesn't match that the char is only a bracket but that string includes a bracket

Answer (score 1):

you can check that char is only a bracket with regex:

```
if char[/\A[({\[]\z/]
  #...
end
```